# node.js can't upload file in integration test

Tags: javascript, node.js, multer

I'm adding integration tests to a legacy code-base prior to refactoring. For this case, uploading a file.

**The Test:**

```
it('uploads a photo at the specified index', done => {

    chai.request(server.instance)
        .post('/profile/photo/0')
        .set('Access-Token', `${token}`)
        .set('API-Key', testConfig.apiKey)
        .field({contentId: 'foobar'})
        .attach('file', fs.readFileSync(__dirname + '/logo.png'), 'file')
        .end((err, res) => {
            console.log(JSON.stringify(res.body))
            res.should.have.status(200)


            done()
        })
})
```

The endpoint being tested works ok in production. But to get the test to pass, I have to comment out the following lines in `make-middleware.js` of the `multer` module:

```
if (!includeFile) {
  // appender.removePlaceholder(placeholder)
  // return fileStream.resume()
}
```

Being inexperienced with node, I must've missed some configuration or something. How can I make my test pass (without modifying an external module's code)?

Comment: Are you 100% confident that `fs.readFileSync(__dirname + '/logo.png')` reads the file? BTW: It would be a good idea to use `path.join( __dirname, 'logo.png' )` so it won't fail on Windows.

Comment: @pawel Yes, absolutely confident that it is read correctly. Good tip about windows, thank you.

Comment: Have you used the endpoint (outside of this test) posting the same file (`logo.png`). Seems like you have defined a file filter for multer on your server and the file is not passing it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`multer` uses `busboy` to get its job done (get / stream files). The lines you've commented just stops the stream :

`fileStream.resume()` in this code is equivalent of `stream.resume()` in `busboy` code, so it just discards the stream :

(from `busboy` documentation)  :

> you should always handle the `stream` no matter if you care about the
>   file contents or not (e.g. you can simply just do `stream.resume();` if
>   you want to discard the contents)

**But Multer is not supposed to behave that way !**

It only behave that way if you pass to Multer a custom `fileFilter` with a callback that sets `includeFile` to false. 
Otherwise, if you don't have `fileFilter` option, Multer uses the following default `fileFilter` (that does nothing) :

```
function allowAll (req, file, cb) {
  cb(null, true)
}
```

And as you can see, the second parameter of the callback is `true`, which is `includeFile`.

So, you can check your custom `fileFilter` if you have one and if you don't, it could be an unexpected side effect and I whish you good luck with it !

Hope it helps,
Best regards

Comment: You're right - it was just fileFilter that I was not aware of. I've asked a related question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/46459194/404201